# Is it possible to decouple specific module implementation in MVVM, so that module functionality dont affect core?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm

my problem is that i have a CoreAPP, in this core app there possibility to active different modules (M1,M2,M3).

CoreApp have a view coreAppview. On that view if M1 is activated than i need to show an aditional button.

Right now there is just a simple if statement which just check config and add button if M1 is activated.

I dont feel very comfortable with just a single if statement between Core functionality and aditional module functionality and i want to be sure that some other developer dont just remove this check.

Are there any ways to decouple this functionality from the Core view in some way?

Comment: What do you mean by **Are there any ways to decouple this functionality from the Core view in some way?**?? I did not understand how it gets coupled with the CoreApp.
I think the best way to achieve your requirement is to either follow the way you're currently having or to handle the view in xaml itself altering the visibility of modules from CoreApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using plugin architecture.
You will need:

- main view model. It will contain collection of loaded and activated plugins;
- some way to load plugins (e.g. MEF);
- `DataTemplateSelector`, which will load data template for plugin's view model. You can implement some convention-based search, e.g., if plugin's view model `M1_ViewModel` is placed in `M1.dll`, then load data template from `M1\Views\M1.xaml`;
- items control (`ItemsControl`, `ListBox`, etc) in your main view. This items control will hold plugins collection and will use mentioned selector to load appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be, to add somthing like "GetAvailableActions" to the module's base class. Then, your CoreApp can call that method after a module was activated and generate the corresponding buttons in the view.